# Set Timestamp on column K when column L only inserted "PAID"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, timestamp, updates

I want to get timestamp only when there is word "PAID" on column L

I used this coding to get update time on column K when I insert anything in column L,

```
`function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Data" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 12 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column L
var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}`
```

I need an upgrade which is only update time on column K if there is "PAID" word in column L. I could use some help here and very much appreciate for the answer, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Data" && e.range.columnStart == 12 && e.value == "PAID") {
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```